# aws eks ip range for eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Does anyone know the ip address range for "https://eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"? I cannot find it in https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Answer (score 0):

EKS runs on EC2.

Currently (it will change frequently), EKS resolves to:

```
eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  A   18.208.64.151
eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  A   34.226.180.204
eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 1  IN  A   54.208.149.145
```

Which feature, respectively, in the current ranges:

```
EC2 | us-east-1 | 18.208.0.0/13
EC2 | us-east-1 | 34.224.0.0/12
EC2 | us-east-1 | 54.208.0.0/15
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve answer of @jonh. To you able to retrieve the IP list of a domain name you can use a DNS Lookup service. You can find it on major of operational system, eg Linux, Windows or you can use an online service eg https://www.nslookup.io/dns-records/eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29806383)